# ampps - python folder and config missing from fresh install

Tags: ampps

I've installed Ampps on Mac OSX and all is well with the exception of the python directory, and respective python.conf file missing from the fresh install altogether. I've been unable to source them, is it intentionally missing for Mac and if not does anyone know where I can get them, or what they should be? Ampps wiki is not helpful, and I've found 2 unanswered questions in various forums for the same issue, but other than that I've found nothing.